# Pasting 1D array VBA - with transpose

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

[image]

I have something that looks like above. Basically I need to split the string and paste it vertically down column C.

```
Sub test()
  Dim str() As String

  str = Split(Range("A1").Value, "/")
  Range("C1").Value = Application.Transpose(str)

End Sub
```

The transpose is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the number of cells for the output.  You are currently only specifiying one cell.

You can use Resize to dynamically set the size of the output range:

```
Sub test()
  Dim str() As String

  str = Split(Range("A1").Value, "/")
  Range("C1").Resize(Ubound(str)+1).Value = Application.Transpose(str)

End Sub
```